# Can dimethyl sulphide be used for ozonolysis of benzene?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, organic-oxidation

There is literature that suggests that ozonolysis of benzene occurs with ozone and $\ce{Zn/H2O}$. Can it take place with ozone and dimethyl sulphide?

Comment: Yes, various reducing agents can be used, dimethylsulphide in particular.

Comment: I agree, DMS is a standard reductive workup for ozonolysis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting the comments into an answer; Yes, DMS can be used in place of $\ce{Zn/H2O}$ during the reductive workup for ozonolysis. The mechanism involves DMS reducing a $\ce{O-O}$ fragment of the trioxolane intermediate produced from ozonolysis by one oxygen and itself oxidizing to DMSO (dimethyl sulfoxide).

[image]

([Image source](https://www.ch.imperial.ac.uk/rzepa/blog/?p=6708))

I did some literature survey and found out that benzene ozonolysis to glyoxal under DMS reductive workup gave 73% yield based on absorbed ozone ([Keaveney et.al. **1969**](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/i360029a017)).